# How to re-render a ListView when the order of the list changes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a To-do list using ListView which takes a list from the state. I am passing it a custom Widget that contains a button to "complete" the todo. When it is pressed, I call a callback function to re-order the list that I have in state, however the ListView is not re-rendered and the list is not re-ordered.

I tried passing a callback function to the child Widget, so that when the "complete" button is pressed, the Screen that contains the ListView re-orders the state.

In the parent component I have this:

```
Widget _renderList(BuildContext context) {
    if (this.todos.length == 0) {
      return Text(
          'You have no Todos yet. Create one by pressing the + button below');
    }

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: this.todos.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext , int index) {
        return TodoListItem(this.todos[index].id, this.sortTodos);
      },
      shrinkWrap: false,
    );
  }
```

and

```
void sortTodos() {
    this.setState(() {
      this.todos = Todo.sortTodosChronologically(todos);
    });
  }
```

and in the child component (TodoListItem):

```
class TodoListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final int todoId;
  final Function() sortTodos;

  TodoListItem(this.todoId, this.sortTodos);

  @override
  createState() => _TodoListItemState(this.todoId);
}

class _TodoListItemState extends State<TodoListItem> {
  final int todoId;
  Todo todo = Todo.blank();

  _TodoListItemState(this.todoId);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.check,
            color: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          onPressed: () => TodoService.completeTodo(this.todo.id).then(
            (Todo todo) {
              this.setState(() {
                this.todo = todo;
              });
              widget.sortTodos();
            },
          ).catchError(
            (error) => errorSnackBar(context, error),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: where is `_renderList` method called? inside `StatefulWidget#build` method?

Comment: It is in a _renderBody function, which itself is called in the StatefulWidget build function